# update rate for unique productId by each userID

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm going to implement a method on my own SQL. I have two tables in MySQL. Suppose that each row is updated in the `FirstTable` and the values of the `rate` and `countView` are variable, I'm trying to update them with the same command:

```
 UPDATE FirstTable SET `countView`= `countView`+1,
                             `rate`=('$MyRate' + (`countView`-1)*`rate`)/`countView`
                             WHERE `productId`='$productId'
```

FirstTable:

```
  productId | countView | rate |     other column  |
------------+-----------+------+-------------------+---
      21    |      12   |   4  |      anything     |
------------+-----------+------+-------------------+---
      22    |      18   |   3  |      anything     |
------------+-----------+------+-------------------+---
```

But in this way, a user can vote every time he wants to. So I tried to create a table with two columns `productId` and `userID`. Like below:

SecondTable:

```
  productId |      userID   | 
------------+---------------|
      21    |      100001   |  
------------+---------------|
      22    |      100002   |   
------------+---------------|
      21    |      100001   |  
------------+---------------|
      21    |      100003   |   
------------+---------------|
```

Now, as in the example given in the `SecondTable`, a user has given to a productId two vote. So I don't want both of these votes to be recorded.

Problems with this method:

1. The value of the counter is added to each vote.
2. I can not properly link the `SecondTable` and `FirstTable` to manage the update of the `FirstTable`.

Of course, this question may not be completely new, but I searched a lot to get the right answer. One of the questions from this site came through this method. Using this method, you can manage the update of a table. This method is as follows:

```
UPDATE `FirstTable` SET `countView`= `countView`+1,
                        `rate`=('$MyRate' + (`countView`-1)*`rate`)/`countView`
    WHERE `productId`='$productId' IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productId, userID
    FROM SecondTable)
```

But the next problem is that even when I use this command, I encounter the following error:

> ## 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

So thank you so much if you can guide me. And I'm sure my question is not duplicate... thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixes your specific syntax problem:

```
UPDATE FirstTable
    SET countView = countView + 1,
        rate = ($MyRate + (countView - 1) * rate) / countView
    WHERE productId = $productId AND
          productId IN (SELECT t2.productId FROM SecondTable t2);
```

But if two different users vote on the same product, `FirstTable` will be updated only once.  It is unclear if that is intentional behavior or not.

Note that `SELECT DISTINCT` is *not* needed in the subquery.

Comment: ThankYou, No, I do not intend to consider a user's vote. So how should the new problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

The error is being generated because you can't return 2 fields in an "in" statement.  You'll want to use group by:

Try:

```
IN ( SELECT DISTINCT productId FROM rating group by product, UserID)
```

Here's documentation to look over for mysql group by if you want: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: Sure thing!  Glad I could help. :)